# What effect were used for manufacturing HDD before 1988?

Tags: computer-science

I understand Hard disk present before [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_hard_disk_drives#1980s,_the_transition_to_the_PC_era)
and I came to know that [Giant magnetoresistance effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance) used in applications in Hard Disk manufacturing and this effect is discovered in [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance#History)

So what effect were used for manufacturing HDD before 1988?

Comment: The same as used for floppy disks, cassette tapes, reel-to-reel tapes, and other applications going back to the early 1900s... The 'giant' effect just meant that the area of a bit could be made much smaller, meaning that washing-machine sized Winchester disk that held 10Mb could become a tiny little 8Tb drive on a keychain.

Comment: @JonCuster I clearly mention in the question that effect is discovered in **1988**. You are saying **1900s**. I am confused.

Comment: The GMR is used on the read head to sense the orientation of the magnetic domains on the media. By making the response 'giant', the size of a domain on the media could be greatly reduced. Before GMR was discovered, well, there is plain old magnetoresistance to read the media. You just end up with a lower data density on the media.

Comment: @JonCuster The disk itself was [the size of a pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IBM_2315_disk_cartridge.agr.jpg), or sometimes [a birthday cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_pack). It was the machine that read the disk that was washing machine sized.

Comment: This question might be more appropriately asked at [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).